# Request.Form and radio button ids

Tags: asp.net, html, radio-button

I have the an approximation of the following

```
input id='rb1' name='rb1' type='radio' 
input id='rb2' name='rb1' type='radio'
```

e.g. both radios share the same name so only one can be selected

I want to be able to use Request.Form to see which one has been selected. However all I get in Request.Form is the name e.g. rb1. Is there any way to detect the actual id of the control that has been pressed e.g. rb1 and rb2?

I dont want to use server controls for this for reasons I'm not going to bore you with.

Comment: I guess I could just give each one a value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input id='rb1' name='rb1' type='radio' value='rb1' />
<input id='rb2' name='rb1' type='radio' value='rb2' />
```

Comment: Cheers, I remembered this just after I posted!